# Ghost script prints blank pages pdfs

Tags: pdf, printing, windows-server-2019, ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript to produce PDFs . The problem is that the PDF that is generated is blank.

After I did a bit of research I found [this solution](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262757). On this page it says that there is a bug with Ghostscript and in order to fix this I need to modify `GSCall` in `/usr/local/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`.

The problem is that I am using Windows and I don't know how to navigate to that location in order to do the modifications.

I am not sure If I understood correctly the solution that is presented on that forum.

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that the generated pdf is blank instead of being filled woth the information that needs to be printed.

Comment: Windows doesn't use CUPS in its printing system so unless you are doing something unusual such as using the Windows Subsystem for Linux CUPS has no relevance to you. **How** are you 'using Ghostscript to produce PDFs' ? What version of Ghostscript are you using ? You will need to supply the input file being sent to Ghostscript and the Ghostscript command line being used before anyone can likely help you.